# tensorflow serving grpc regress request

Tags: tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving

Currently making rest request to tf_serving using the Classify and Regress API (see https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest).

```
{
  "signature_name": <string>,
  // Optional: Common context shared by all examples.
  // Features that appear here MUST NOT appear in examples (below).
  "context": {
    "<feature_name3>": <value>|<list>
    "<feature_name4>": <value>|<list>
  },
  // List of Example objects
  "examples": [
    {
      "<feature_name1>": <value>|<list>,
      "<feature_name2>": <value>|<list>,
    },
    {
      "<feature_name1>": <value>|<list>,
      "<feature_name2>": <value>|<list>,
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to make the same request through grpc. But all documentations I can find are using the prediction API and the input are `"inputs"` or `"instances"`.
I'm having trouble using the `tf.make_tensor_proto` function to construct the request. I want to keep using the `context` `example` format if possible. The documentation is sparse on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the reason for using regress api is because i need to predict hundreds of examples at once. have the same heavy feature. trying to save on serialization time

Comment: Could please take a look at this  
 https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest#classify_and_regress_api, hope it helps.Thanks